# Will cakephp 1.3.2 work on php 5.3?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Will cakephp 1.3.2 work on php 5.3 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

There's really nothing more complicated to it. I've got it set up on the mac I'm typing this from.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You will need to uncomment `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` and replace `UTC` to your timezone in app/config/core.php.

Comment: Why would that be? I certainly didn't have to do that.

Comment: It's a PHP weirdness - documented.

Comment: Otherwise you will get this warning: "Warning (2): strtotime() [http://php.net/function.strtotime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are required to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Paris' for '2.0/DST' instead [CORE\cake\libs\cache.php, line 570]"

Comment: That would be because I have a timezone set in my php.ini.